# Loop through excel files in subfolders

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to loop through my files in different folers 
the first part of the code is working :

```
   from os import walk
   import pandas as pd 


   path = r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\test2'
   my_files = []
   for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
   my_files.extend(filenames)

   print(my_files)
```

the code successfully print all the files with my subfolders 
however the problem comes in this part when I try to extract excel columns different files and save them in a directory

```
 all_dicts_list = []
 for file_name in my_files:

#Display sheets names using pandas
pd.set_option('display.width',300)
mosul_file = file_name
xl = pd.ExcelFile(mosul_file)
mosul_df = xl.parse(0, header=[1], index_col=[0,1,2])

#Read Excel and Select columns

mosul_file = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = 0 , 
index_clo=None, na_values= ['NA'], usecols = "C , F ,G")

#Remove NaN values

data_mosul_df = mosul_file.apply (pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
data_mosul_df = mosul_file.dropna()

#Save to Dictionary

datamosulx = data_mosul_df.to_dict()
all_dicts_list.append(datamosulx)
```

## all dictionaries will be in all_dicts_list

I get an error **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory** I don't understand the problem or how to fix it. 
Thank you

Comment: specify the line where you get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` also fix your identation, in `python` it's important.

Comment: the problem strat from line : xl = pd.ExcelFile(mosul_file)

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to extract specific columns from diffrent excel files that are located in different subfolders

Comment: where is the error coming from? i.e. during `pd.read_excel`? based on the first bit of code it looks like you're saving only the file names and not the entire file path (i.e. `my_files.extend([os.path.join(dirpath, fname) for fname in filenames])`

Comment: Hey it works thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell because you might have lost some of the formatting from copy and pasting but make sure that after the

```
for file_name in my_files:
```

anything that you want in the for loop needs to be indented with tabs or spaces to the same level.

print out mosul_file after allocating it to see whether this could be the case and then indent appropriately.

Comment: all lines are aligned under my_files: and I am able to print mosul_file but i get the same problem when i try to print le line after (mosul_df)

Comment: Can you format you question with the indents appearing as they appear in your code? the preview should be able to give you a hand with it.